# What is this component in my drone?

Tags: identification, drone

I am disassembling a drone for a project. I found this silver boxy component on a side circuit board that connects to the main circuit board on one side, and to the camera of the drone on the other side. It has a small black thing sticking out of it, so I don't know exactly what it is. Could anyone identify it?
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't take the "don't turn it on, take it apart" principle too serious. Sometimes it's good to use a product. If you had turned the drone on at least once, that should have given you an immediate feeling of what that component is good for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SPDT slide switch

Five pin through hole.  Middle three pins are for switch, outer pins are housing.